# Having trouble combining data

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

I'm new to using R and am struggling with lots of errors.  So this is probably a basic question. I'm trying to combine two datasets using the cbind function

I'm trying this:
data3 = cbind(data_cluster,km)

km is k-means clustering

This is the error I'm getting:
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
cannot coerce class ‘"kmeans"’ to a data.frame

How do I get this to work?

Comment: The cbind() function is used to combine two data frames column-wise. The error message indicates that you are trying to combine a data frame with a kmeans object, which is not a data frame.

Comment: A data frame is made up of columns. If you want to bind the predicted cluster to each row of your data frame, then you probably want to extract the `cluster` vector from the `km` object. Try `cbind(data_cluster, cluster = km$cluster)`